# How to prevent React + code splitting from overwriting SSR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I'm using SSR to render HTML. I'm using Webpack's code-splitting, so after React loads, it fetches the chunks. While it's fetching, it doesn't know what to display. If I `return null`, React overwrites the SSR'ed HTML and replaces it with a white screen. After the chunks load, React renders content again.

How can I get React to not overwrite the SSR'ed HTML? Is it possible for React to not render anything until all the chunks are loaded?